# Composition of pushforwards

Tags: differential-geometry, pullback, pushforward

I am trying to verify the following identity, where $M,N$ and $P$ are differentiable manifolds $\phi : M \rightarrow N$ and $\psi: N \rightarrow P$ are smooth maps between manifolds. Also, $f: P \rightarrow R$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function whose domain is a subset of the manifold P: $$(\psi \circ \phi)_{\star} = \psi_{\star} \circ \phi_{\star}. $$ However, I am getting the composition in reverse order.

Edit: The definition for the pushforward $\phi$ is given as:

$$ (\phi_{\star} X_{p})_{\phi(q)}(f) := X_{q}(\phi^{\star}f)  $$

Let $q \in M$. By the definition of the pushforward:

EDIT:
$$[(\psi \circ \phi)_{\star}X_{q}]_{\psi \circ \phi (q)} (f) : = X_{q} [(\psi \circ \phi)^{\star} (f)] = X_{q} [(\phi^{\star} \circ \psi^{\star}) (f)] = X_{q} [\phi^{\star} (\psi^{\star}(f))] = (\phi_{\star}X_{q})_{\phi(q)}[\psi^{\star} f] = [(\psi_{\star} \circ \phi_{\star})X_{q}]_{\psi \circ \phi (q)} (f)$$
Hence, $(\psi \circ \phi)_{\star} = \psi_{\star} \circ \phi_{\star}$.

EDIT: I understand that we can do it with the chain rule if M has a set of local coordinates $x^{\mu}$, $N$ has a set of coordinates $y^{\nu}$ and $P$ has a set of local coordinates $z^{\lambda}$. In that case,using Einstein summation notation

$$[(\psi\circ \phi)_{\star} X_{q}]_{\psi\circ\phi(q)} = X^{\mu} \frac{\partial y^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial z^{\lambda}}{\partial y^{\nu}} \frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\lambda}} $$

The transformation $\phi_{\star}$ is represented locally by the Jacobian $\frac{\partial y^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}$ and $\psi_{\star}$ by the locally by the Jacobian $\frac{\partial z^{\lambda}}{\partial y^{\nu}}$.

Hence,

$$[(\psi\circ \phi)_{\star} X_{q}]_{\psi\circ\phi(q)} = (\psi_{\star})^{\lambda}_{\nu}(\phi_{\star})^{\nu}_{\mu}X^{\mu} \frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\lambda}}$$

But I don't see how this fixes the order of multiplication of the matrices.

Comment: Your first equality is wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin the definition?

Comment: Yes. You are not applying the definition correctly.

Comment: It's important to distinguish between the differential $d_p\phi:T_pM\to T_{\phi(p)}N$ of a map $\phi:M\to N$, and the pushforward $\phi_\ast$. If $X$ is a vector field on $M$, then $\phi_\ast X$ isn't a vector field on $Y$ in general. Some definitions say it isn't defined, while some definitions define it as a vector field *along* $\phi$ - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)#Pushforward_of_vector_fields for example. Before answering your question, it would be useful to understand in what sense you mean $\phi_\ast$.

Comment: You changed it and the first equality is *still* wrong. Why don't you write down the definition with *one* map ($[\phi_\star(Y)]_{\phi(p)}(f) = $?)?

Comment: @TedShifrin Is it correct now?

Comment: @user17945 Sorry for the sloppy mistaken notation. I meant to say that if $X_{q}$ is a vector in the tangent space at $q \in M$, then $\phi_{\star} X_{q}$ is a vector in the tangent at $\phi(q) \in N$.

Comment: @saad Your second "Edit:" is correct, so I'm not clear what the problem is now. Note your original equation $(\phi\circ\psi)_\star = \phi_\star\circ\psi_\star$ is not correct, since the composition $\phi\circ\psi$ is not defined.

Comment: @user17945 Sorry $\psi \circ \phi$.